# How to associate an element in one Array with an element in another array (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
float [] E;
float [] Location;
```

The elements in array E are the following: `{1900, 16400, 77666, 8000, 13200, 15600}`

The elements in array Location are `{Birmingham, Blackburn, London, Luton, Manchester, Newcastle}`

These data have been extracted from my database where they are associated, meaning:

```
Birmingham - 1900
Blackburn - 16400
London - 77666
Luton- 8000
Manchester-13200
Newcastle-15600
```

I want to be able ensure that the locations are associated to the right data as I have shown above if that makes sense. Is there a way of doing that?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: use same index to fetch data from both arrays

Comment: Can't you just save it in a HashMap? Or did I misunderstood something?

Comment: You have a `Location` class. You could add the data there?

Comment: @MuratK.: They don't, they have a poorly-named `Location` variable.

Comment: ay this is confusing.

Comment: You can obviously use whatever conventions you want to in your own code, but when asking others for help, please follow at least the main conventions: Variable names and field names do not start with capital letters, class names do.

Comment: The given examples for locations are Strings, not floats.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they're already associated  by index. The entry at index 0 in `E` is related to the entry at index 0 in `Location`.

But I would solve this by **not** having two arrays. Instead, I'd have a single array storing an object, which had (for example) both the float 1900 (I wouldn't use `float`, though; at least use `double`) and the string `"Birmingham"`.

```
class SomeAppropriateName {
    private double distance;
    private String location;

    SomeAppropriateName(double distance, String _location) {
        this.distance = _distance;
        this.location = _location;
    }

    // ...add getters and setters as appropriate...
}
```

Then:

```
SomeAppropriateName[] info;
```

Comment: @Addy: It depends entirely on how the information is being used, which the OP hasn't shared with us. A `HashMap` **may** be appropriate, or not. Normally when presented with arrays, I assume order matters.

Comment: And the OP should consider using a `List` instead of an array.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Again, it depends entirely on the use case. `List<SomeAppropriateName>` may well be a better, or worse, choice than `SomeAppropriateName[]`.

Comment: @Addy I disagree that a HashMap associating indexes would make life easier than a class which directly associates data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [android.util.Pair<F,S>](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) for that.

```
List<Pair<String,Double>> pairs = Arrays.asList(
    new Pair("Birmingham", 1900),
    new Pair("Blackburn", 16400),
    new Pair("London", 77666),
    new Pair("Luton", 8000),
    new Pair("Manchester", 13200),
    new Pair("Newcastle", 15600)
);

for (Pair<String, Double> pair : pairs) {
    Log.d("log", pair.first + " - " + pair.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply with HashMap !

HashMap is an array with key value. You can iterate on it etc.. For example this code :

```
 HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

  /*Adding elements to HashMap*/
  hmap.put(12, "Chaitanya");
  hmap.put(2, "Rahul");
  hmap.put(7, "Singh");
  hmap.put(49, "Ajeet");
  hmap.put(3, "Anuj");

  /* Display content using Iterator*/
  Set set = hmap.entrySet();
  Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
     System.out.print("key is: "+ mentry.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
     System.out.println(mentry.getValue());
  }

  /* Get values based on key*/
  String var= hmap.get(2);
  System.out.println("Value at index 2 is: "+var);

  /* Remove values based on key*/
  hmap.remove(3);
  System.out.println("Map key and values after removal:");
  Set set2 = hmap.entrySet();
  Iterator iterator2 = set2.iterator();
  while(iterator2.hasNext()) {
      Map.Entry mentry2 = (Map.Entry)iterator2.next();
      System.out.print("Key is: "+mentry2.getKey() + " & Value is: ");
      System.out.println(mentry2.getValue());
   }
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
i don't know how you're querying your database, but i assume you're making one query to get both the location and the distance. 

//1. create a model to represent the Location and its corresponding distance
public class LocationDistance {
    private float distance;
    private String location;

    public LocationDistance(float distance, String location) {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getLocation(){
        return this.location;
    } 

    public float getDistance(){
        return this.distance;
    }

    public void setLocation(String loc){
         this.location=loc;
    } 

    public void setDistance(float distance){
         this.distance=distance;
    }
}

   //2. Loop over the two arrays and create a list of LocationDistance
    List<LocationDistance> locationDistance=new ArrayList<LocationDistance>();
    float[] e = { 1900f, 16400f, 77666f, 8000f, 13200f, 15600f };

    String[] location = { "Birmingham", "Blackburn", "London", "Luton", "Manchester", "Newcastle" };

    for(int i=0; i<e.length;i++){
      locationDistance.add(new LocationDistance(e[i],location[i]));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

is e a float, the same as location?

you should define a Pojo class for that

```
class Pojo {
    private final float e;
    private final String city;

    public Pojo(float e, String city) {
        this.e = e;
        this.city = city;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final float[] e = { 1900f, 16400f, 77666f, 8000f, 13200f, 15600f };
        final String[] location = { "Birmingham", "Blackburn", "London", "Luton", "Manchester", "Newcastle" };
        final Pojo[] p = new Pojo[e.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
            p[i] = new Pojo(e[i], location[i]);
        }
    }

}
```